# jQuery closest method not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What I'm trying to do is add the class .div-initial to the div with the class .nav-content-wrap if it contains less than or equal to one UL. The problem is it adds the class .div-initial to all other divs not just the closest div.

Here's my HTML:

```
<ul id="nav">
   <li><a href="./">Government</a></li>
   <li><a href="./">Community</a>
      <div class="nav-content-wrap">
         <ul>
            <li><span>Dropdown header here</span></li>
            <li><a href="./">Dropdown link</a></li>
            <li><a href="./">Dropdown link</a></li>
            <li><a href="./">Dropdown link</a></li>
            <li><a href="./">Dropdown link</a></li>
            <li><a href="./">Dropdown link</a></li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </li>
   <li><a href="./">Visitors</a></li>
   <li><a href="./">Business</a></li>
   <li><a href="./">How Do I...?</a></li>
</ul><!-- /#nav -->
```

My jQuery code is:

```
if($('.nav-content-wrap ul').length <= 1){
   $(this).addClass('div-initial');
}
```

Also, how do I wrap all ULs inside the div tag with `<div class="col-md-6"></div>` if there's more than one then wrap it with `<div class="col-md-12"></div>` if there's only one.

I tried using this code but it didn't work. It seems to be selecting all the ULs in my document.

```
if($('#nav ul').length >= 1){
   $(this).find('ul').wrap('<div class="col-md-6"></div>');
}
```

Comment: <div class="nav-content-wrap> is missing the double quotes at the end before >. Should be <div class="nav-content-wrap">

Comment: Hi. Yes even with the double quotes my script won't load.

Comment: You will need to use $().each(function(){$(this)}); in order to access the $(this) variable in that way

Comment: Am i mis-understanding something, or, is your question oddly missing any code that actually uses .closest?

Comment: Sorry, while editing my question, I was changing my jQuery code. Sorry about that. I got a downvote just because of that? Didn't know it was this strict here in StackOverflow.

Comment: I found it unclear due to that. You stated jQuery closest method isn't working, but.. you aren't using it, so... how could it be not working. not clear. It is also unclear as far as what `this` is, since you didn't include the enclosing function or how the enclosing function is executed.

Comment: Did any of the answers meet your needs? If so, could you mark the answer of your choice as accepted or else leave a comment?

Answer (score 0):

The value of `this` is not set as you think it is, as you are not in a jQuery callback function when you use it. The `if` condition will not set it for the code that follows.

Instead do this:

```
if($('.nav-content-wrap ul').length <= 1){
   $('.nav-content-wrap').addClass('div-initial');
}
```

If your page is such that you could have more than one `div` with the `nav-content-wrap` class, then the above is not good enough, as the situation might be different per such `div`. In that case loop over these elements:

```
$('.nav-content-wrap').each(function() {
    if ($(this).find('ul').length <= 1) {
        $(this).addClass('anything');
    }
});
```

... and extended with the code that wraps `ul` elements with `div`s:

```
$('.nav-content-wrap').each(function() {
    var $lists = $(this).find('ul');
    if ($lists.length.length <= 1) {
        $(this).addClass('anything');
        $lists.wrap('<div class="col-md-6">');
    } else {
        $lists.wrap('<div class="col-md-12">');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For each matching ul, get the closest nav-content-wrap and add div-initial class.

```
   $('.nav-content-wrap ul').each(function(i, obj){
        // <ul> found, so get the parent
        var $parent = $(obj).closest('.nav-content-wrap');
        // Then search for child ul
        var $ULs = $parent.find('ul');
        if($ULs.length <=1)
            // Add your class to it
            $parent.addClass('div-initial');
        // Wrap them and assign 6 or 12 depending on the number of children
        $ULs.wrap('<div class="col-md-' + ($ULs.length > 1 ? 6 : 12) + '">');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first jQuery code is looking for all `ul` elements inside of `nav-content-wrap`, if it finds <= 1 of them, then it tries to add a class to `$(this)`.  In that case, `$(this)` is likely not what you expect unless your code block is wrapped in another jQuery statement.

What you can do instead is look at each `nav-content-wrap` individually and see how many `ul` elements each one has, adding the `div-initial` class as needed.

The wrapping in divs can be handled in the same area with the jQuery .wrap method.

```
$('.nav-content-wrap').each(function(i, item){
  var ulChildren = $(item).children('ul');
  if(ulChildren.length <= 1){
    $(this).addClass('div-initial');
    ulChildren.wrap('<div class="col-md-12"></div>');
  }else{
    ulChildren.wrap('<div class="col-md-6"></div>');
  }
});
```

The `.each` function is part of jQuery, it is used to loop through a collection of items, in this case it will loop through all elements with the class `nav-content-wrap`.

When using `.each`, `i` is an iteration variable, it will start at 0 and count up by one for each time through the loop. item is the actual `nav-content-wrap` element.

Comment: What is i and item for inside (function(i, item)? I'm new to this programming language. Anyways your code worked. Thanks!

Comment: Added some clarification to my answer for what i and item mean, and what the .each function is doing.